# The package name of all the jar files from androird framework codes is "android"?

Tags: java, android, frameworks

I got a problem about is it true that **the package name of all the jar files from android framework source codes is "android"?**

I knew framework-res.apk's package name is "android", and all the android core processes named "system", but **what's relationship between "android" package name and "system" process name?**

And I really want to know which files or jars in the frameworks belong to "android" package.

Can anyone help me understand it more deeply? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all the classes are there in "android" package. You can take a look at the code and see the complete package structure :
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base